# JBoss ESB Message is received by the wrong Service

Tags: jboss, jms, esb, jboss-messaging, jboss-esb

I have several services configured in jboss-esb.xml, when I send message to one of the service, my message will be received by one of the configured services (even though the message is not meant for that service)!

If I send the same message again, another service will process that message (in round-robin maner), it is not random, it is like each service takes turn to intercept the message.

Example, if I have 3 services configured. First time I send a message, Service 1 will receive it, second time I send a message, Service 2 will receive it, third time I send the message, Service 3 will receive it. Fourth time I send it, Service 1 will receive it and the cycle repeat..

I suspect there is something wrong with the way I configured my jboss-esb.xml, but I am clueless.

Here is how I invoke the service,

```
ServiceInvoker invoker = new ServiceInvoker("NTIAdaptor", "SearchAccountByParentInternalId");
Message replyMessage = invoker.deliverSync(requestMessage, TIMEOUT);
```

And here is the jboss-esb.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jbossesb parameterReloadSecs="5"
 xmlns="http://anonsvn.labs.jboss.com/labs/jbossesb/trunk/product/etc/schemas/xml/jbossesb-1.0.1.xsd"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://anonsvn.labs.jboss.com/labs/jbossesb/trunk/product/etc/schemas/xml/jbossesb-1.0.1.xsd http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbossesb/trunk/product/etc/schemas/xml/jbossesb-1.0.1.xsd">
 <providers>
  <jms-provider connection-factory="ConnectionFactory" name="JMS Provider">
   <jms-bus busid="NTI">
    <jms-message-filter dest-name="queue/NTIAdaptor" dest-type="QUEUE"/>
   </jms-bus>
  </jms-provider>
 </providers>
 <services>  
  <service category="NTIAdaptor"
   description="SearchAccountByExternalId" name="SearchAccountByExternalId">
   <listeners>
    <jms-listener busidref="NTI" name="JMS"/>
   </listeners>
   <actions mep="RequestResponse" webservice="true">
    <action class="com.krona.esb.action.AuthenticateAction" name="authenticate"/>
    <action class="com.krona.esb.action.LogAction" name="logStart"/>
    <action
     class="com.krona.esb.account.action.SearchAccountByExternalIdAction"
     name="process" process="process"/>
    <action class="com.krona.esb.action.LogAction" name="logEnd"/>
   </actions>
  </service>
  <service category="NTIAdaptor"
   description="SearchAccountByInternalId" name="SearchAccountByInternalId">
   <listeners>
    <jms-listener busidref="NTI" name="JMS"/>
   </listeners>
   <actions mep="RequestResponse" webservice="true">
    <action class="com.krona.esb.action.AuthenticateAction" name="authenticate"/>
    <action class="com.krona.esb.action.LogAction" name="logStart"/>
    <action
     class="com.krona.esb.account.action.SearchAccountByInternalIdAction"
     name="process" process="process"/>
    <action class="com.krona.esb.action.LogAction" name="logEnd"/>
   </actions>
  </service>
  <service category="NTIAdaptor"
   description="SearchAccountByParentInternalId" name="SearchAccountByParentInternalId">
   <listeners>
    <jms-listener busidref="NTI" name="JMS"/>
   </listeners>
   <actions mep="RequestResponse" webservice="true">
    <action class="com.krona.esb.action.AuthenticateAction" name="authenticate"/>
    <action class="com.krona.esb.action.LogAction" name="logStart"/>
    <action
     class="com.krona.esb.account.action.SearchAccountByParentInternalIdAction"
     name="process" process="process"/>
    <action class="com.krona.esb.action.LogAction" name="logEnd"/>
   </actions>
  </service>
  <service category="NTIAdaptor"
   description="SearchAccountByServiceExternalId" name="SearchAccountByServiceExternalId">
   <listeners>
    <jms-listener busidref="NTI" name="JMS"/>
   </listeners>
   <actions mep="RequestResponse" webservice="true">
    <action class="com.krona.esb.action.AuthenticateAction" name="authenticate"/>
    <action class="com.krona.esb.action.LogAction" name="logStart"/>
    <action
     class="com.krona.esb.account.action.SearchAccountByServiceExternalIdAction"
     name="process" process="process"/>
    <action class="com.krona.esb.action.LogAction" name="logEnd"/>
   </actions>
  </service>
 </services>
</jbossesb>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are experiencing that problem because you're using the same jms-bus across services. Try using a different jms-bus for each service jms listener.

Comment: But if my JMS is configured in such a way that it publishes the messages to all the services listening to it, then would all msgs reach not to all services? Do I need to configure different JMS in such case also?

Answer (score 0):

If is not what Manuel says, we had a similar problem to yours, messages were getting to the wrong services. 
In our case it was that the juddi register wasn't altered when we changed a listener from one services to another. So we ended with 2 services listening to the same queue.